# What NO-SQL solution is optimised for frequent view updates & recreation?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, amazon-dynamodb, bigtable, nosql

I am having a situation where every newly entered data set to a table prompts the re-creation of a number of views. I am currently trying CouchDB, but would appreciate feedback about other database solutions.

Description: The table includes a number of fields, including an array of objects.

The view needs to scan through these array of objects according to some conditions (e.g. obj-field answer=yes).

this creates some intensive view-recreation for every view whenever a new table entry is made..

```
Original Data:
1: [A, B, C, D, ..]
2: [A, B, C, D, ..]
3: [A, B, C, D, ..]
..

View 3)
A: [1, 2, 3, ..]
B: [2, 4, 6, ..]
C: [1, 5, 6, ..]
..

View 4)
A: [2, 3, 7]
C: [3, 5, 8]
..
```

Both, original data and the views are queried with similar regularity.

More detailed explanation:

There s a use-case that is difficult to handle in mysql, as tables become to long. So I am thinking of implementing No-sql.

users give feedback to standardised questions which comes in as an array of objects - usually about 60 objects per feedback from one author for one target user. these objects are essentially standardised answers (e.g. yes, no, maybe) with an intensity indicator (e.g. a-little, somewhat, very).

Additionally some demographic and relational data (age, location, position, etc.) come in as well.

while saving this data is straight-forward - the question is how to optimise the analytical part of the feedback, which requires updating the view(s) with every feedback that comes in.

the views not only summarise feedback objects, but re-order the feedback arrays. currently i do this client-side running for-loops for every field - but i m afraid this will be too slow once too much feedback is received. this is for a mobile app, so resources are limited.

A) my question is.. which no-sql database is most suited for this ( i currently try couchDB).

B) i m also wondering about the efficiency of the "views" - especially as feedbackObj-related views need to get completely updated once new data is added (see 3) and 4) below).

C) or should i focus more on a manually implemented caching solution server or client side?

```
author_id,
target_id,
[
    feedbackObj: 
    {
         question,
        answer: yes/no/maybe,
        intensity: a-little, somewhat, very,
        ...
    }
]
```

1) feedback by author for target_user=1 and answer_type:
(e.g. all feedback for target_user=1 with answer=yes)

```
author_id : [ feedbackObj-1, feedbackObj4, .. ]
author_id : [ feedbackObj-3, feedbackObj9, .. ]
```

2) return only feedbackObjects that were answered with "yes" for a certain target_user=1, sorted by author_id

```
author_id : [ feedbackObj-1, feedbackObj2, .. ]
author_id : [ feedbackObj-1, feedbackObj2, .. ]
```

3) return only feedbackObjects that were answered with "yes" for a certain target_user=1, sorted by feedbackObj (because the questions are standardised)

```
feedbackObj-1: [ authorID-1, authorID-3, ..]
feedbackObj-2: [ authorID-1, authorID-10, ..]
```

... here the stored data needs to go through a lot of processing.

4) e.g. feedback by feedbackObj-1-Value (e.g. all yes), and intensity indicator (a little, very, somewhat)
(for target_user = 1)

```
feedbackObj-1: [ authorID-1, authorID-3, ..]
feedbackObj-2: [ authorID-1, authorID-10, ..]
```

Answer (score 0):

A) it's crucial to know how often you need to access the data. I think you'll have to consider different ways you optimize your data.

Infrequent access in chouchdb means that you'll trigger a reindex across all changes when you look at the view. You could call the stale view with update-after if up-to-date results are not required. If you do that you might also want to keep the documents in different

Couchbase does the opposite and updates view indexes on update of the document I believe.

2) Speaking for couchdb, reducing by expanding an array is not optimal - reduce is meant to provide short responses. But couchdb is quite fast if you just return key pairs per document. Return a key like [feedbackObj_1, authorId-1] You can then reduce to just a count. If you need the response for FeedbackObj-1 you can use startkey and endkey to get all the author-ID objects.

So you'd have one view `feedbackbyauthor` that would look like this:

```
function(doc){
    // you may need to do some filtering to just emit on feedback documents here
    emit([doc.author_id, doc.feedback_id], null)
}
```

You could then query with the parameters `startkey=[AUTHOR_ID,]&endkey=[AUTHOR_ID, {}]&include_docs=true`

See [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html).

3)Regarding caching solution check the stale-views. that may be helping you to control the number of times you actually need to reindex.

**Update**

Given the throughput, I'd expect that Couchbase is more suitable for your needs. I've not used it as much, but it's [very similar in it's map reduce logic to couchdb](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb). I added an example how a view for your use case could be written in couchdb.

Comment: A) at peak times, very popular target_users will get feedback between 100 and 500 times a day. extreme cases are higher. normally times its 5-10 feedback per day.

2) i know, the tricky part here its not so much about summing up feedback but analysing people with similar feedback-objetcs, similar answer patterns and similar demographics..

3) I ll look into caching solutions, thanks for your the quick rely..

Comment: A way to straighten out this data structure could be to create a table for every single target_user containing all the feedbackObjs the user received (together with the author_id and question/answer), this way caching and map/reduce can be implemented more straight forward. For feedback by 100 authors, answering 50 questions each, the table would contain 5000 single feedbackObjs... naturally, this means that the database will have to deal with many many tables - as many as AppUsers there are... (10,000 or 100,000)... does this make sense?

Comment: Furthermore, every single of these target_id tables would need a number of views by map/reduce. 10.000 tables x 10 views per table = 100.000 views..

Comment: I made some changes to above hoping it's more suited to your scale.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input. I ll give couchbase a try :-)